# Android application crashes immediately upon opening

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm developing an android application and after I hit run, I unlock the AVD and click the menu to load my application and I immediately get a "The application closed unexpectedly" message.

The following is the output of my logcat:

```
02-21 11:36:55.952: D/AndroidRuntime(329): Shutting down VM
02-21 11:36:55.952: W/dalvikvm(329): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaughtexception (group=0x40015560)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.throughputconverter/com.throughputconverter.ThroughputConverterActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.throughputconverter.ThroughputConverterActivity.onCreate(ThroughputConverterActivity.java:44)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-21 11:36:55.971: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you paste line 44 in ThroughputConverterActivity.java

Comment: paste your code? It would b easier if i could see whole thing but i can speculate it has something to do with:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText

Comment: Actually, through inspection, I found the issue I was having. I had two widgets called the same thing and it was messing up. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're casting the EditText widget incorrectly or that the widget doesn't exist in your layout and/or Activity.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are casting an object to EditText but this object is not of this kind:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
```

Could you provide line 44?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same error

searched everything for the cause
nothing was working in my case
then carefully looked in to resource xml

I changed recently added element

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/bClick2"
android:background="@drawable/new1"
android:layout_gravity="bottom">
</Button>
```

to

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/bClick2"
android:background="@drawable/new1"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
```

and my problem got solved.